# mocha -d, node-inspector, node debug all freeze with sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, sails.js, mocha.js

I'm using `sails 0.11` with `mocha`. When I add a `debugger;` inside a mocha test and then run `mocha -d`, the server lifts properly but then freezes within the test.

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

above the server lift output I see `Debugger listening on port 5858` so I tried going to `localhost:5858` and I see the following:

```
Type: connect
V8-Version: 4.1.0.25
Protocol-Version: 1
Embedding-Host: node v1.6.2
Content-Length: 0
```

I think this might be deeper though. It actually does a similar thing when I try `node debug app.js`. Funny enough debugging works when I do `node --debug app.js` though, so maybe `mocha -d` is using `node debug` internally.

I have researched this and found that other people are having problems with sails and debugging which again makes me think it might have to do with that. https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2670

I also tried `node-inspector` and it is showing a similar problem where it freezes.